# How to Store bulk data in 'Local Storage' using phonegap in Iphone

Tags: iphone, cordova, local-storage

Im developing an appication using phonegap. 
The local storage of data using phonegap is done using key-value pairs and same in the case of retrieving. 
I want to store and retrieve bulk data. How to do it using Phonegap in Iphone. I am now using the methods

to retrieve-       `var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");`

to store--        `window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");`

Plz help me in this,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't know if I got you right. Are you looking for a solution to retrieve multiple sets of data from the localStorage?

Comment: yes, to store and retrieve bulk data..

Comment: What about naming your keys like this "key1", "key2", "key3", "key4" and then you could use a for(var i=0;i<10;i++) loop to get all the values from your storage

Answer (score 0):

You can add any JSONeable value, like objects, arrays or a XML node :)

Use this plugin: www.jstorage.info